# Cannot find System.Windows.Point

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, ui-automation, point

I am using `UIAutomation` with the method

```
System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.FromPoint(System.Windows.Point)
```

to get the element by the mouse cursor, but I cannot find the type `System.Windows.Point`. I looked up object library and it is still unseen.

I am using .Net Framework 4.5.

Comment: `System.Windows.Point` is part of WPF, if you're trying to do this in a WinForms app, it's not supported.

Comment: Add a reference to "WindowsBase".

Comment: @HansPassant can you please convert that comment into answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.Windows.Point is part of WPF, if you're trying to do this in a WinForms app, it's not supported – Peter Ritchie Oct 4 '14 at 0:10

Answer (score 0):

As @HansPassant said, you have to add a reference to 'WindowsBase'.
I am just adding the answer as the comment might go overlooked.